# jQuery :contains with specific string crash browser

Tags: jquery

For this issue, I'm using jQuery to check if listbox 'To' contains a string that match listbox 'From'.

But with 1 string, I get a complete freeze (same on IE8 or Chrome). Developper Tools has the same problem (freeze and no error mesage). No javascript errors before executing the code.

Here the code

```
$('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ 'Verifier periodiquement annuellement les installations electriques par un personnel qualifie (entreprise ou organisme de contro' +')')[0]
```

I'm trying several tests, and the parenthese seems involved in the crash.
But this is working :

```
$('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ 'Vérifier périodiquement, annuellement les installations électriques par un personnel qualifié entreprise ou organisme de contrô' +')')[0]    
$('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ '((((((((((Vérifier (((périodiquement(((, (((annuellement ((((les ((((installations (((((électriques ((((par (((((un personnel ((((((qualifié (((((entreprise ou organisme de contrô' +')')[0]
$('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ '(Vérifier périodiquement, annuellement les installations électriques par un personnel qualifié entreprise ou organisme de contrô' +')')[0]
$('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ 'Plan de Continuité d'Activité (PCA)' +')')[0]
```

So what is the problem with this string 'Vérifier périodiquement, annuellement les installations électriques par un personnel qualifié (entreprise ou organisme de contrô' ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: the code is more complex (text in quote is coming from variable, but only this would crash on any browser.

Comment: if there are special characters in the string, you must escape them with \\

Comment: Reconsider, find another way, whatever! Oh the horror. Those selectors will be inefficient and a bitch to maintain, and special characters must be escaped.

Comment: $('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ 'Verifier periodiquement annuellement les installations electriques par un personnel qualifie \\(entreprise ou organisme de contro' +')')[0] is crashing too. So it is not an escaping issue. And by this way, no one of this working example should be working.

Comment: Seems like a quote problem : does this work ? $("#LstProposeTo option:contains("+ "'Verifier periodiquement annuellement les installations electriques par un personnel qualifie (entreprise ou organisme de contro'" +")")[0]

Comment: Not working too. But I think it's really the parenthese, because if I close the parenthese as this : $('#LstProposeTo option:contains('+ 'Verifier periodiquement annuellement les installations electriques par un personnel qualifie (entreprise ou organisme de contro)' +')')[0] It is working. So why jQuery seems try to interpret as code a string ?

Comment: which version of jquery do you use ? Anyway, your contains filter should be enclosed with quotes or double quotes because it is not equal to a single word.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.6.2. What did you mind by enclosed with double quote ? I don't understand why jquery check this string as a code portion.

Comment: The quotes can be single or double, but they should be there because you have more than one bare word. See http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/  "As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to have been a bug since jQuery 1.3.2

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5607 "**:contains() selector doesn't support parentheses**"

this bug has been filed as duplicate of other bugs, which seem to have finally been fixed in jQuery 1.8

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3778

Hope this will help